# how to copy the contents of hard drive to a external media using live cd

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, hard-drive

i am currently on a live CD and i want to copy down all the data present in my hard disk now so in short how to do it.

i am in trouble. i want to recover all the files that were saved in my hard disk partition sda6 
Ubuntu has crashed and thats the reason i want to do so

i cannot login into ubuntu what i have last just before is i installed yed graph editro through these commands

```
wget http://www.yworks.com/products/yed/demo/yEd-3.12.2_64-bit_setup.sh
chmod +x yEd-3.12.2_*-bit_setup.sh 
./yEd-3.12.2_*-bit_setup.sh
```

has that command made my files unexecutable

Comment: What file format is the drive?

Comment: why was this downvoted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

`sudo dd conv=sync,noerror bs=8k if=/dev/sda6 of=/home/backup-file`

Then you can copy `backup-file` to external drive and later use it to get your saved data.

When later you want do that you would need to mount it, so run:

`sudo losetup /dev/loop1 /home/backup-file`

`sudo mount /dev/loop1 /mnt/backup`

If you have not much data to backup with low dispersion over the drives/partitions, if it's all rather in one or a few folders then wouldn't it be easier to save those folders/files straight to the external disk?

Comment: the terminal output comes as permission denied when i run the first command

Comment: Needed root privileges, so run with `sudo`, see in my answer.

Comment: the output comes as failed to open , no such file or directory

Comment: In the first command I changed `/path/to/backup` with `/home/backup-file`

Comment: please see my edited question

Comment: pease see my updated answer